# Unable to understand the combination of Bootstrap Grids for various screen sizes

Tags: html, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I found one code snippet on codeply.com and modified a bit to understand the combination of col-xl, col-lg, col-sm and col-xs. Here is the code snippet.

http://www.codeply.com/go/bipCPFM4mU

I am a newbie to Bootstrap. So, please let me know if the code snippet has been implemented in a wrong way and its output might be unpredictable. That being said here are my questions:

1. For the last 3 divs (div for 1.1 .. 4.1, div for 1.2 .. 4.2 and div for 1.3 .. 5.3), there are two xl specification i.e. col-xl-3 and col-xl-6 then why does it take only col-xl-6 into consideration not col-xl-3 (for **xl** screens)? I tried to reverse the order but there was no difference in the output. All *.1 sections and *.2 sections were on the first row and then *.3 were on the second row.
2. When you open the output in another window and resize the width to make the screen size to **lg**, then 1.3, 2.3, 3.3 and 4.3 disappear. And, how do the rest of the elements figure out the column size. I am assuming that they take on the full width because I haven't specified anything for col-lg.

I hope my questions make sense. I have tried looking at a number of examples but it does not answer my questions and help me understand why is it behaving the way it is behaving.

Can someone please help?

Thank you,
Jayant

Answer (score 1):

1. You can't include 2 declarations in the same size category - xl, so declaring 3 columns and 6 columns at the xl width will always result in just one as they are just width declarations really. I think it's probably a typo and should be col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-sm-12.
2. They haven't disappeared, they are just hidden by 5.3 which is full width at that screen size and floating in front of them. If you contain 5.3 in a class="row" or give it a clear:both style you will see 1.3 - 4.3 again.

Bootstrap layout is hard to get your head around initially until it clicks.

Hope that helps :)